# Java chess move with Jframe and Jpanel

Tags: java, class, jframe, jpanel, chess

I'm trying to create a chess game with java jframe and jpanel.

I have done a method which allows you to move the pieces everywhere, but I don't know how to create methods for every single piece like pawn, king...

MAIN App.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Image;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LivX1XKpSQA&ab_channel=ScreenWorks

public class App {

    //linked list of all pieces
    public static LinkedList<ChessPiece> listPieces = new LinkedList<>();   //TODO why static?

    public static ChessPiece selectedPiece = null;
    public static Pawn selectedPawn = null;

    public static int xPos;
    public static int yPos;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //da un immagine prelevo tutti i vari pezzi
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\ricca\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\gamesthread-pgv-inc\\src\\chess.png"));
        Image img[] = new Image[12];

        int i = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < 400; y+=200){
            for(int x = 0; x < 1200; x+=200){
                img[i] = bi.getSubimage(x, y, 200, 200).getScaledInstance(64, 64, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                i++;
            }
        }

        //Assegno i vari pezzi alle loro posizioni di partenza

        //white pieces
        ChessPiece towerW1 = new ChessPiece(0, 7, true, listPieces, "tower");
        ChessPiece horseW1 = new ChessPiece(1, 7, true, listPieces, "horse");
        ChessPiece bishopW1 = new ChessPiece(2, 7, true, listPieces, "bishop");
        ChessPiece queenW = new ChessPiece(3, 7, true, listPieces, "queen");
        ChessPiece kingW = new ChessPiece(4, 7, true, listPieces, "king");
        ChessPiece bishopW2 = new ChessPiece(5, 7, true, listPieces, "bishop");
        ChessPiece horseW2 = new ChessPiece(6, 7, true, listPieces, "horse");
        ChessPiece towerW2 = new ChessPiece(7, 7, true, listPieces, "tower");

        ChessPiece pawnW1 = new ChessPiece(0, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW2 = new ChessPiece(1, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW3 = new ChessPiece(2, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW4 = new ChessPiece(3, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW5 = new ChessPiece(4, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW6 = new ChessPiece(5, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW7 = new ChessPiece(6, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnW8 = new ChessPiece(7, 6, true, listPieces, "pawn");
        
        //black pieces
        ChessPiece towerB1 = new ChessPiece(0, 0, false, listPieces, "tower");
        ChessPiece horseB1 = new ChessPiece(1, 0, false, listPieces, "horse");
        ChessPiece bishopB1 = new ChessPiece(2, 0, false, listPieces, "bishop");
        ChessPiece queenB = new ChessPiece(3, 0, false, listPieces, "queen");
        ChessPiece kingB = new ChessPiece(4, 0, false, listPieces, "king");
        ChessPiece bishopB2 = new ChessPiece(5, 0, false, listPieces, "bishop");
        ChessPiece horseB2 = new ChessPiece(6, 0, false, listPieces, "horse");
        ChessPiece towerB2 = new ChessPiece(7, 0, false, listPieces, "tower");

        ChessPiece pawnB1 = new ChessPiece(0, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB2 = new ChessPiece(1, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB3 = new ChessPiece(2, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB4 = new ChessPiece(3, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB5 = new ChessPiece(4, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB6 = new ChessPiece(5, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB7 = new ChessPiece(6,1, false, listPieces, "pawn");
        ChessPiece pawnB8 = new ChessPiece(7, 1, false, listPieces, "pawn");

        //Creazione del frame che contiene la scacchiera

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 512, 512);  //setto la grandezza della finestra (x e y definiscono la posizione del frame nello schermo, gli altri due la altezza e larghezza)
        frame.setUndecorated(true);     //rimuovo i bordi e la barra in alto, in modo tale da non avere spazi bianchi intorno alla scacchiera

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                
                boolean white = true;

                //creo la scacchiera con le caselle di colori differenti
                for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
                        if(white){
                            g.setColor(Color.white);
                        }
                        else {
                            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                        }

                        //TODO coloro caselle attorno a un pezzo
                        // if(selectedPiece != null){

                        //     // System.out.println(xPos);
                        //     g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                        // }

                        g.fillRect(x*64, y*64, 64, 64);     //grandezza delle caselle, 64*8=512 quindi width/height del frame, le caselle sono larghe 64
                        
                        white = !white;     //per alternare i colori delle caselle se bool white = true allora metto false, dunque verrà colorata la prox di black, e cosi via
                    }
                    
                    white = !white;     //per alternare i colori delle caselle se bool white = true allora metto false, dunque verrà colorata la prox di black, e cosi via
                }

                for(ChessPiece p: listPieces){

                    int i = 0;

                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("king")){
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("queen")){
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("bishop")){
                        i = 2;
                    }
                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("horse")){
                        i = 3;
                    }
                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("tower")){
                        i = 4;
                    }
                    if(p.pieceName.equalsIgnoreCase("pawn")){
                        i = 5;
                    }
                    if(!p.white){
                        i+=6;
                    }

                    //disegno i pezzi nella scacchiera
                    g.drawImage(img[i], p.x, p.y, this);

                }
            }
        };
        frame.add(panel);

        //per muovere i pezzi
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {    //permette di ricevere l'input dal mouse

            //autogenerated methods di MouseListener()
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                //faccio un if, se è un pezzo bianco print di white + namePiece, else print black + namePiece
                System.out.println((getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).white?"white ":"black ") + getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).pieceName);     //senza .pieceName print hash code dello scacco
                
                selectedPiece = getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY());

                System.out.println("x pos: " + getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).xPosition);
                System.out.println("y pos: " + getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).yPosition);

                xPos = getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).xPosition;
                yPos = getPiece(e.getX(), e.getY()).yPosition;

                // int xy = e.getX();
                System.out.println("x and y pos: " + xPos + " " + yPos);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "king"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a king");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                }
                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "queen"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a queen");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                }
                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "pawn"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a pawn");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

                    selectedPawn = (Pawn) selectedPiece;    //cast to Pawn

                    
                }
                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "bishop"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a bishop");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                }
                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "horse"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a horse");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                }
                if(selectedPiece.pieceName == "tower"){
                    System.out.println("The piece is a tower");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                }

                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                
                selectedPiece.movePiece(e.getX()/64, e.getY()/64);
                
                frame.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }

        });

        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

                if(selectedPiece != null){

                    selectedPiece.x = e.getX()-32;  //-32 posiziona il mouse al centro dell'immagine dello scacco quando la prelevo
                    selectedPiece.y = e.getY()-32;

                    frame.repaint();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                
            }
        });
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //usata in void mousePressed del MouseListener
    public static ChessPiece getPiece(int x, int y){    //TODO method from the class

        int xPosition = x / 64;
        int yPosition = y / 64;

        for(ChessPiece p: listPieces){

            if(p.xPosition == xPosition && p.yPosition == yPosition){
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

CHESS class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ChessPiece {
    
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;

    int x;
    int y;

    LinkedList<ChessPiece> listPieces;  //linked list of all pieces
    String pieceName;

    boolean white;

    public ChessPiece(int xPosition, int yPosition, boolean white, LinkedList<ChessPiece> listPieces, String pieceName){
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;
        this.white = white;

        x = xPosition * 64;     //TODO prima messe dopo tutti gli if come: g.drawImage(img[i], p.xPosition*64, p.yPosition*64, this);
        y = yPosition * 64;

        this.listPieces = listPieces;
        listPieces.add(this);
        
        this.pieceName = pieceName;
    }

    public void movePiece(int xPosition, int yPosition){

        if(App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64) != null){
            
            if(App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64).white != white){
                
                App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64).eatPiece();
        
            }
            else{   //nel caso provi a mangiare una pedina dello stesso coloro mi riporta alla posizione di prima
                x = this.xPosition * 64;
                y = this.yPosition * 64;
                return;
            }
        }

        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;

        x = xPosition * 64;
        y = yPosition * 64;
        
    }

    //per rimuovere dalla lista uno scacco mangiato
    public void eatPiece(){
        listPieces.remove(this);
    }
}
```

PAWN class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Pawn extends ChessPiece{
    
    public Pawn(int xPosition, int yPosition, boolean white, LinkedList<ChessPiece> listPieces, String pieceName){
        super(xPosition, yPosition, white, listPieces, pieceName);

        this.pieceName = "pawn";
    }

    public void movePiecePawn(int xPosition, int yPosition){

        if(App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64) != null){
            
            if(App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64).white != white){
                
                App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64).eatPiece();
        
            }
            else{   //nel caso provi a mangiare una pedina dello stesso coloro mi riporta alla posizione di prima
                x = this.xPosition * 64;
                y = this.yPosition * 64;
                return;
            }
        }

        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;

        x = xPosition * 64;
        y = yPosition * 64;
        
    }
}
```

What you suggest me to do?

Thank you very much!

I don't know how to create every particoular move for every tipe of piece.

Comment: static means it's not specific to an instance of a class, it doesn't have access to the member variables and methods of an instance of a class. App.main is the entry method into the program and is static, i.e. there is no instance of App class. You could make all of that stuff non-static then use a `var app = new App();` to create an instance of App and e.g. `app.listPieces` to access it. For your use case, that is not necessary, but something for you to think about.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is declare an abstract isValidMove method that each piece can override, then call it from movePiece.

```java
public abstract class ChessPiece {

    public void movePiece(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        if (!isValidMove(xPosition, yPosition))
            return;

        if (App.getPiece(xPosition, yPosition) != null)
            ; // eatPiece?
        ...
    }

    public abstract boolean isValidMove(int xPosition, int yPosition);

}
```

Pawns are actually pretty annoying to start with, because of the double step move, different capture vs movement, different direction based on color, and en passant. I'll get your gears turning with the rook (aka tower).

```java
public class Tower extends ChessPiece {

    public boolean isValidMove(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        // Can't move to the same position.
        if (xPosition == this.xPosition && yPosition == this.yPosition)
            return false;

        // Check for friendly piece on target square.
        ChessePiece targetPiece = App.getPiece(xPosition*64, yPosition*64);
        if (targetPiece != null && targetPiece.white == this.white)
            return false;

        if (xPosition == this.xPosition) { // Same file
            // Check if any pieces are in the way.
            int startY = Math.min(this.yPosition, yPosition)
            int endY = Math.max(this.yPosition, yPosition)
            // Check every position excluding the start and endpoint
            for (int i = startY + 1; i < endY; i++)
                if (App.getPiece(xPosition*64, i*64) != null)
                    return false; // Something is in the way.

            // You'll eventually need to make sure the king is not in check...
            return true;
        } else if (yPosition == this.yPosition) { // Same rank
            // Check if any pieces are in the way.
            int startX = Math.min(this.xPosition, xPosition)
            int endX = Math.max(this.xPosition, xPosition)
            // Check every position excluding the start and endpoint
            for (int i = startX + 1; i < endX; i++)
                if (App.getPiece(i*64, yPosition*64) != null)
                    return false; // Something is in the way.

            return true;
        } else { // Not in same rank or file.
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Scanning for check gets weird. You need to move the piece, scan, then move it back if the king is in check. I'd wait until you have all the pieces moving properly to deal with that headache.